# React - How to mock child components and get them to callback the parent?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocking, tdd

I want to unit test a component that has 2 children.

The component under test is responsible for rendering the first child component. Then, when the user has finished interacting with the first child, the first child will callback the parent via an onComplete callback.

When the parent component is called back it will use state and conditional rendering to hide the first child and display the second child.

I hope my example makes sense. Imagine a page where a user interacts with a component (i.e. click, enter text etc). It then disappears and another component appears.

I want to unit test the parent component separate from the children. Ideally, I would like to mock the children. But i'm not sure how to get the mock of the child to callback the parent in my test.

My current tests use real children. Which means when a child changes I have to change the parent test. (I.e. I click some text on the child to trigger a callback to parent in my parent test. If i want to change the text on the child, I have to change my parent component's test to click the changed text). (this is obviously an enormous pain in the bum)

Here is an example of what i'm trying to test:

```
export default class ExampleParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      part1Complete: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    let part1, part2;

    if(!this.state.part1Complete) {
      part1 = <Part1 onComplete={this._handlePart1Complete.bind(this)} />
    } else {
      part2 = <Part2 />
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {part1}
        {part2}
      </div>
    );
  }

  _handlePart1Complete() {
    this.setState({ part1Complete: true });
  }
}
```

A further example could be:

The first child calls-back the parent with a result.

Depending on the value of the result, the parent may render part2 or part3 next.
How can we trigger the callback on the mock child AND get it to callback with a certain result (so we can test the logic of rendering part2 or part3).

Hope this makes sense.

Look forward to hearing from you